# Problem closing WSClient in Playframework

Tags: java, playframework, wsc

I have a Problem with the WSClient in playframework.

When i send a request closing the WSClient in the finally Block after :

```
 public WSResponse sendPostRequest(String url, String bodyAsJson,  Map<String,List<String>> headers) throws Exception {
        WSResponse response;
        CompletionStage<WSResponse> wsResponseCompletionStage;

        try {
            //Headers
            WSRequest request = ws.url(url);
            request = mapHeaderParams(headers, request);
            //sending request to api......
            wsResponseCompletionStage = request.post(bodyAsJson);
            request.getHeaders().put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic "+ "xyz"));
            response = wsResponseCompletionStage.toCompletableFuture().get();
            logger.debug("Response Data from Api : " + response.getBody());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error Posting Data to Api : " + e.getMessage());
            ws.close();
            throw e;
        }finally {
            ws.close();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

i always get an error when i want to send the next Request :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Closed

..and when i dont close my ws client, it is constantly logging in my application.logs like this and dont stop it at all :

> debug] o.a.n.c.DefaultChannelPool - Closed 0 connections out of 1 in 0
>   ms [debug] o.a.n.c.DefaultChannelPool - Entry count for :
>   https://api.com:443 : 1 [debug] o.a.n.c.DefaultChannelPool -
>   Closed 0 connections out of 1 in 0 ms [debug]
>   o.a.n.c.DefaultChannelPool - Entry count for :
>   https://api.com:443 : 1 [debug] o.a.n.c.DefaultChannelPool -
>   Closed 0 connections out of 1 in 0 ms

.. so the WSClient never closes!

Here is my WebClient Class :

```
@Singleton
public class ApiRequestClient{

    @Inject
    private WSClient ws;

    final Logger.ALogger logger = Logger.of(this.getClass());

    @Inject
    public ApiRequestClient(WSClient ws) {
        this.ws = ws;
    }


    public WSRequest mapHeaderParams(Map<String, List<String>> headers, WSRequest request) {
        //not working !!!! ....
        //request.getHeaders().putAll(headersa);
        //thats why we do ......
        Set keySet = headers.keySet();
        for(Object key : keySet){
            request.setHeader(key.toString(), headers.get(key).get(0));
        }
        return request;
    }


    public WSResponse sendPostRequest(String url, String bodyAsJson,  Map<String,List<String>> headers) throws Exception {
        WSResponse response;
        CompletionStage<WSResponse> wsResponseCompletionStage;

        try {
            //Headers
            WSRequest request = ws.url(url);
            request = mapHeaderParams(headers, request);
            //sending request to api......
            wsResponseCompletionStage = request.post(bodyAsJson);
            //FIXME !!!!
            request.getHeaders().put("Authorization", Arrays.asList("Basic "+ "xyz"));
            response = wsResponseCompletionStage.toCompletableFuture().get();
            logger.debug("Response Data from Api : " + response.getBody());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error Posting Data to Api : " + e.getMessage());
            ws.close();
            throw e;
        }finally {
            ws.close();
        }
        return response;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> queryStringToParameterMap(Map<String, String[]> queryString) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Set<String> keys = queryString.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            params.put(key, queryString.get(key)[0]);
        }
        return params;
    }

}
```

Anyone knows this strange Behaviour??

THX a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to close `WSClient` manually after each call until you use dependency injection. Play will handle it creation on start up and clean up it on shutdown automatically. This is done in [AhcWSModule](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-ahc-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/ahc/AhcWSModule.scala) by subscribing on application [stop hook](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-ahc-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/ahc/AhcWSModule.scala#L78).

You need to call `close` method only when creating `WSClient` manually as described in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWS#Directly-creating-WSClient).